# Periodic PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation does not exist errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a strange, intermittent problem with a simple query in a Rails 6.0.0 app.

```
class Series < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :observed_series  
end

class ObservedSeries < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :series
end

# On the contact class:
def managed_series
  Series.joins(:observed_series)  # Actually more complex, but I'm able to dupe with this simple version
end
```

Calling `managed_series` works **every time** in the console.

However, when called as part of a view, **it works the first time**, but reloading the page and I get this error:

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "observed_series" does not exist LINE 1: ...".* FROM "salesforce"."series__c" LEFT OUTER JOIN "observed_... ^`

Restarting the server or make a code change, refresh, and it works. Refresh again, the error comes up.

The table and relationships exist, and as I mentioned above, it works both in console and the first time I load the page. When the error comes up, if I type `Series.joins(:observed_series)` into the console, I get the same error.

I've tried stopping and restarting Postgres, and another dev has been able to replicate this on their machine, so I don't think it's something weird on my computer.

Comment: Could it be that it works in the console every time because the query is cached and not being called more than once? The 2 models do not inherit the same class (`ActiveRecord::Base` vs `ApplicationRecord`). Do you have any logic in `ApplicationRecord`?

Comment: That's a good point about caching in the console. ApplicationRecord doesn't have anything special, and Series actually descends from SalesforceRecord; I was simplifying the problem a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has something to do with the naming convention of models and tables and there's a violation of `Convention over Configuration` here, can you make sure the table names of models `Series` and `ObservedSeries` are `series` and `observed_series` respectively. If yes, can you try running this AR query instead

```
Series.joins("INNER JOIN observed_series")
```

Also, if naming convention is the issue, its better to define the table name explicitly in models using

```
self.table_name = 'xyz'
```

Let me know what you get!

Comment: Your suggestion to manually create the join led me to figure out what was going on. The observed_series table was in a different schema than the rest of the tables (we're syncing with Salesforce, and there's a separate schema for the Salesforce tables). By manually setting the join and prefixing it with the schema, everything's now working properly. I don't understand why this would work sometimes and not others, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Thanks!

Comment: @TimSullivan Great! Can you please accept the answer if it helped you debug the issue?